# Translate code from c# in vb (complex raise event)

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have this piece of code which I am not able to translate from c# to vb:

```
  // subscribe for errors that occur when applying changes to the client
((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Program_ApplyChangeFailed);
```

it must be somethink like this :

```
DirectCast(syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider, SqlSyncProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += New EventHandler(Of DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs)(AddressOf Program_ApplyChangeFailed)
```

I got an error which is saying:

***'Public Event ApplyChangeFailed(sender As Object, e As Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.***

I do not know what/how to raise this even! is too complex for me :(

Can someone help me?

Comment: The C# code is adding an event handler for the change failed event.  The VB equivalent would be `AddHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how VB handles the eventhandler but judging from the msdn article:

```
AddHandler DirectCast(syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider, SqlSyncProvider).ApplyChangeFailed, AddressOf New EventHandler(Of DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs)(AddressOf Program_ApplyChangeFailed)
```

Comment: with this code I got the following error: **'AddressOf' operand must be the name of a method (without parentheses).**